# How can i pass all the username from firestore to ejs to display on my users.ejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, ejs

I already fetch all the data from my database, but i want to display it to my users page(users.ejs)

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    let usersData = db.collection('users');
    let query = usersData.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log('No matching documents.');
          return;
        }  

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.data())
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });

    res.render('users', {title: 'Users'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the entire array as mentioned below and can show it using the loop in the ejs template:

```
 res.render('users', {
      users: users // Array of all the users.
    });
```

**Users.ejs**

```
<html>
<head>
    <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
    </header>

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-1-1">
            <div class="body-content">
                <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
                    <h1><%= user.name %></h1>
                    <% }); %>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>



<footer>
    <% include ../partials/footer %>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps!